# MongoDB new driver manager regex query same as MySQL LIKE query

Tags: php, mongodb

I am using php7 and MongoDB new driver manager in my project. I want one query which is same mysql LIKE query

Below are my search feild in my MongoDB collection:-

fullAddress: 1013 BISMARCK ROAD PUNTA GORDA FL 33983 US

I want one query to find all records who belongs to "33983" value.

Below are my code:-

```
 new MongoDB\BSON\Regex("^33983", 'i')
```

but its not working it s showing no records found error but this result set actully present in database i want LIKE query which is same in mysql Like query ('%LIKE%').

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an updated Query with `like` query using `MongoDB`. Here is full documentation https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/regex/

```
    $requestlist = '33983';
    $options = ['limit' => 10, 'skip' => 0, 'sort' => ['listprice.listprice' => 1]]; 
    $dataSend = array('listingStatus' => 'Active');
    $nameCondition = []; $nameCondition[] = array('fullAddress' => new MongoDB\BSON\Regex($requestlist)); 
    $nameCondition[] = array('mlsNumber' => new MongoDB\BSON\Regex($requestlist)); 
    $dataSend['$or'] = $nameCondition;
    $query = new MongoDB\Driver\Query($dataSend,$options); 
    $rows = $manager->executeQuery("TableName.Collection", $query);
```

Hope this will help :)

Comment: Tried above solution but not working. I am using 'fullAddress' => new MongoDB\BSON\Regex("^$request->list", 'i')

Comment: instead of `new MongoDB\BSON\Regex("^$request->list", 'i')` try `"/*.$request->list.*/"`

Comment: @ShivrajRamHipparge Put your whole query here for better understanding

Comment: @ShivrajRamHipparge check updated query. `$options = ['limit' => 10, 'skip' => 0, 'sort' => ['listprice.listprice' => 1]]; 

$dataSend = array('listingStatus' => 'Active'); $nameCondition = []; $nameCondition[] = array('fullAddress' => new MongoDB\BSON\Regex($request->list)); 

$nameCondition[] = array('mlsNumber' => new MongoDB\BSON\Regex($request->list)); $dataSend['$or'] = $nameCondition; 
$query = new MongoDB\Driver\Query($dataSend,$options); 
$rows = $manager->executeQuery("TableName.Collection", $query); `

Comment: @ShivrajRamHipparge Query is updated as my answer here. You are welcome :)